# UCC SSL certificate across multiple machines and IPs

Tags: ssl, ucc

I have some doubts concerning the UCC certificates.

From what I understand, they can be used to offer SSL to several domains using only 1 certificate file.

However, in all sites that I search, UCC SSL options always refer to "Microsoft® Exchange Server" or as being "ideal" for Microsoft technologies. Also, they are not clear about multiple IPs... and, obviously, I don't have a great deal of know-how on these subjects...

So, I have the following questions, assuming that I buy a UCC certificate for 3 domains:

1. can I use a single certificate to "secure" **www.domainA.com**, **domainB.pt** and **domainC.co.uk**?
2. can I use that same certificate on webservers, **located on different machines, with completely different IP addresses**?
3. can I use that same certificate with **Apache2**?

More specifically, I'm currently looking at GoDaddy options:

- http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=9039

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.

That said, some UCC providers would consider these sort of uses violations of the terms of service for the UCC.

Comment: How so? Why could it be considered a violation of the terms of service? Because of the domains being unrelated?

Comment: Some UCC vendors license on a per-server basis, some require that the domains on the certificate be part of a single business unit, etc.