# Clarification of Godaddy UCC SSL on multiple servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, godaddy, ucc

After reading [UCC SSL certificate across multiple machines and IPs](https://serverfault.com/questions/517097/ucc-ssl-certificate-across-multiple-machines-and-ips)

I have follow up questions.

The first server is running with a GoDaddy UCC SSL.
www.exampleA.com

I would like to use for www.exampleB.com the UCC SSL because of what above said it would work.
I went inside the SSL on GoDaddy and added www.exampleB.com

I received a validation email - confirmed it.

My www.exampleB.com server is an EC2 instant. All documentation that exist in installing Ec2 SSL revolves around creating a .csr (or .pem) file submitting and downloading the server.crt and the key.

Note once did GoDaddy asked me for CSR, the download option is not available and its been a day that i have waited.

Questions are:

1. AWS's guide shows that .pem is the prefered method to upload the 
   cert as it requires .pem, all known method are with .csr. Can I
   convert file extension without effort. (using a mac osx to
   communicate with Ec2's AWS-CLI)
2. Did i miss a step in order to
       properly use UCC in giving www.exampleB.com the UCC cert.
3. Do i have to wait for the 72hrs for the previous UCC expire.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use GoDaddy.